# DEP and ASLR and how to use it?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, dep, aslr

[ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) are two techniques that are used to protect applications from hackers. With many modern applications becoming more security-aware, these techniques are becoming more important. For now, I just focus on Windows 7 and these techniques. I wonder when and how I can best use these techniques, especially when developing desktop applications by using developer tools other than .NET compilers. (For .NET security, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172710/how-do-i-enable-dep-or-aslr-for-my-net-application) will provide an answer.) I'm especially interested in compilers like Delphi and C++Builder but also other WIN32 compilers.
Basically, how do I get those applications to support both DEP and ASLR? And is there some way that I can control these options from within my own (WIN32) code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a matter of using the right linker option so it flips a bit in the executable header.  The Microsoft linker options are /NXCOMPAT (DEP) and /DYNAMICBASE (ASLR).  I don't know your tools well enough to know if they have similar options.  Editbin.exe supports these options too, you can always run it in a post-build event.

Answer (score 0):

```
{$SetPEOptFlags $100}//to set the ASLR flag

{$SetPEOptFlags $40}//to set the DEP flag
```

Comment: You're 10 years late! :-)