# Unable to load native dll from c# project (DynamicBase)

Tags: .net, aslr

In Visual Studio I created a C# executable that loads a clr library which then calls loadlibrary on a 64bit native dll an internal exception message box is shown.  If I change the executable to be clr and set advanced option Randomized Base Address to No (/DynamicBase:NO) on the exe project, it loads fine.  How to I get a native .net exe to not use ASLR??  Furthermore, how do I get this scenario working under IIS? -Thanks

Comment: What is the result of GetLastError() after it fails?

Comment: The call to LoadLibrary never returns.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the DLL, deadlocking in DllMain() or some such

Comment: It definitely doesn't like getting loaded with DynamicBase enabled, but it's a third party dll and scenario 2 works (clr exe)

Comment: I'd try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172710/how-do-i-enable-dep-or-aslr-for-my-net-application

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  Is there a way to tell ngen to disable DynamicBase?  This still wouldn't fix the problem when hosting under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. /HIGHENTROPYVA is enabled on native .net exes by default.  using link -edit /HIGHENTROPYVA:no test.exe removed it and fixed the problem.