# How do I enable DEP and ASLR flag for my wpf .net core application?

Tags: aslr, dep

I have a WPF .net core 3.1 windows application, where `DEP/ASLR` flags are showing `TRUE` in some machines and `FALSE` some machines.

> So can I force enable `DEP/ASLR` flag for my application alone
> regardless of machine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172710/how-do-i-enable-dep-or-aslr-for-my-net-application